# Updating row while iterating through ResultSet takes a lot of time

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to improve a data transfer program that I wrote. I am looking for suggestions on how to make it quicker.
My program extracts data from a database (usually Oracle 11g) by filling a ResultSet and writing this result into a file. The program looks periodically into the tables and queries if a special column has changed. For example, this could be such a query:

`select columnA, columnB from scheme.table where changeColumn = '1'`

Now comes the critical part. After extracting the data I need to update this `changeColumn` to `'0'`. Since I have just used the ResultSet for exporting the data into a file I have to rewind it, so the code looks like this:

```
extractedData.beforeFirst();
while (extractedData.next()) {
    extractedData.updateString("changeColumn", "0");
    extractedData.updateRow();
}
```

Now if this ResultSet is bigger (let's say more than 100.000 entries) then this loop can take hours. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to increase the performance of this?
I heard of setting the fetch size to a bigger value, but usually the ResultSet only contains less than a dozen entries. Is there a way to dynamically set the fetch size?

Comment: Use a JDBC Batch Update....

Comment: have you make your resultset updatable.

Comment: yet it is updateable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JDBC Batch Update. From all the row that needs updating, take the primary key on the row that needs updating, add it to a batch update (SQL query) and execute the batch.

A good example from [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/) shows you how to do JDBC Batch Update with JDBC PreparedStatement.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have knowledge of the table's primary key columns at this point. So I guess I cannot build the statements neccessary for the batch.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Most return a `ROWID` implicitly so you can use it for update.

Comment: The program currently exports data from various database types (Oracle, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, DB2, H2). At least H2 does not support the row id (yet).